# Minus in equation for a wave

Tags: waves

I know that the equation of a wave is
$$y(x,t)=A×\cos(kx-\omega t+\phi) \;.$$

I'm curious as to why there is a minus sign in the argument of the cosine function.

Comment: Note that waves and oscillators are different. What you have there is for a wave. The equivalent for a SHO would be $y(t) = A \cos(\omega t + \phi)$. People tend to write these things in whatever way makes their upcoming math neater, so you see a lot of variations in the form they take when written down. It is worth your time to work out what it does when you change the minus to a plus.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine you choose $kx-\omega t+\phi$ so the cosine is +1, i.e $kx-\omega t+\phi=0$ for instance.  Then as time increases, you need to increase $x$ to keep the factor $kx-\omega t+\phi$ equal to $0$: the maximum travels to the right, i.e. the position $x$ of this maximum is increased with time.  Your wave then travels in the positive $x$ direction.

If you were to have $kx+\omega t+\phi$, the wave would be travelling in the negative $x$ direction.

---

Edit: 
Note that, in a standing wave, the time and spatial part of the full interfering wave separate:
$$
A\cos(kx-\omega t)+A\cos(kx+\omega t)= 2 A \cos(kx)\cos(\omega t)\, .
$$
The maxima are stationary in space, at values of $kx$ so that $\cos(kx)=\pm 1$, whereas the nodes are also stationary, with $kx$ such that $\sin(kx)=0$.

Comment: The sense of what you say is great. On the other hand, saying "right" and "left" is potentially misleading because someone could define the positive $x$ direction to be left or up or northward, etc. Your answer would be better if you eliminated left and right, and simply talk about positive $x$ and negative $x$ directions.

Comment: @BillN : good point.  fixed as per your suggestion.

Comment: If the $\omega t $ term is removed, would the wave equation then be describing a standing wave?

Comment: @KFerreira : just updated my answer to include your follow up comment.